# iptables: separate clients from each other

Tags: security, iptables, subnet

is there a way to separate clients in a subnet so that they cannot reach each other?

The infrastructure currently looks like this:

- 192.168.0.1/24 Gateway, a CentOS box with iptables.
- 192.168.0.10-20 Some clients which may reach each other
- 192.168.0.30 A single client which

  - should not be able to reach the hosts 192.168.0.10-20
  - should be able to reach the gateway and the internet

I don't know if it is possible, maybe you could give me your ideas how it could be done. I cannot influence the machine 192.168.0.30 because it is a virtual machine I want to rent to someone. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The rule you need in your FORWARD chain is:

```
iptables <insert spec> -s 192.168.0.30 --dst-range 192.168.0.10-20 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

`<insert spec>` depends on the existing rules. See the output of `iptables -L` and the `iptables(8)` man page for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - but how could I avoid the host reaching the 10-20 hosts directly? Usually this is not transferred via the default route - so the firewall should not see these packages normally.

Is there a easy solution or do I have to seperate the Network into VLAN's and bridge them on the firewall?